# Windows XP Network installation from Linux server (RHEL 5)

Tags: linux, windows-xp, rhel5

**How can I make network installation (for install Windows XP) from Linux (RHEL 5 Server)?**

- There is an option in Linux server to install client machine with Linux by network installation.
- As same as Windows server have option to install client machine with Windows operating system.

Now I want to know steps for

> **Linux server (RHEL5) to install client machine with Windows operating system (Windows XP)**

Comment: Just to be clear about this; you want Windows XP machines to boot Windows XP through a network from a Linux machine? *without Windows boot files on the Linux machine?*

Comment: Why is this Community Wiki? Did the OP reach the edit limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you really need. But for me it sounds like you want to setup a PXE boot which will serve a installable image of windows XP to bare metal machines in your network. If this is the case just [setup PXE boot](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/ch-pxe.html) on your RHEL machine. And create images of windows to served from the boot menu you can use Clonezilla see clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/#use for details.

Comment: @wu, i want that same thing, I don't know name PXE boot. So can't ask my doubt clearly, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Linux boot sector information and Windows boot information are quite different so it is quite difficult to configure both from same installation server especially from Linux server, but there is a scenario when use solutions like Acronis PXE server, that will install an image of existing system on the rest of the systems, in your case I think this option is workable.